# PHP PDO on Windows Server 2003 R2

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pdo, windows-server-2003

I need to use PHP PDO with Microsoft SQL on Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2

I have found that the PHP driver is obsolete:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

And I should use this one from Microsoft:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx

The problem is that this one from MS is not compatible with MS Windows Server 2003 R2.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170%28SQL.90%29.aspx ? it seems to be compatible with windows server 2003. You can then use sqlsrv_ functions in your php code with this driver.

Comment: But there isn't support for PDO for what I've understood, right?

Comment: I am not sure but looks like the support for PDO is experimental so you might be better off using sqlsrv_ functions. What about this one though: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php ?

Comment: Thanks, tomorrow I will have the server (hopefully) and I'll test it.

Comment: I've installed the 2012 version, problem "solved".